# fixedsys font size 11 missing on Window Server 2008

Tags: windows, fonts, windows-server-2008

Using Windows Server 2008 (Sp 2, Datacenter edition), my favourite 11-pixel sized fixedsys font seems not to be available (tested via notepad -> Font browser).

Same method showed this to be available on Windows 7.

Is there any way to make this specific font size available on Windows Server?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is only available via DPI scaling: Start -> control panel -> Personalization -> Adjust font size (DPI) -> set it to 120 DPI